# need to display Icon near to field label in LWC for Combobox

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-design-system, slds, slds-grid

I have t create one icon and need to show near to field name for combobox in modal window
below is my code

```
<div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
    <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large">
        <lightning-card title="" variant="narrow">
        
            <lightning-icon  size="xx-small" alternative-text="help" icon-name="utility:info" title="Name" variant="info"></lightning-icon>                             
            
            <lightning-combobox 
                name="Name"
                label="Name"
                placeholder = "Please select Name"
                options = ""
                value = "" 
                onchange ="">
            </lightning-combobox>
            
        </lightning-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

but its coming like this
[image]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

trying to re-arrange elements within a lightning-component is never a good idea, you probably wan to use a [combobox blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/combobox/) instead,

this way, you can place your icon next to the

```
<my-icon>
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-2" id="combobox-label-id-131">My Label</label>
```

and simply arrange with css.

Comment: can you please provide more details .how i can place icon next to combo box field name/label .I am not getting what you are trying to say. Could you please help me to provide any example if possible

Comment: This is existing component and lightning-combox is used everywhere and its now bit difficult to change it to slds combox blueprint. Will consider that option as optimization, But current requirement standpoint do we have any solution

Comment: placing an icon next to a label is basic web development, i'd suggest you have a look at [Css Basics](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/) it really is not complicated. as per replacing multiple comboboxes, once you code it once, it should be trivial to replace multiple components across your code.